# Нужна Ruby реализация curl_init() метода эквивалентного на Php

Tags: php, ruby

Есть код на Php:

```
 $timestamp = '1485942173'
 $api_key = '6t7a7c34914c0fa02f34b4b52d55aa2bb2f3b4b7';
 $login = 'admin';
 $phone = '79793665627';
 $return = 'json';
 $sender = 'admin';
 $text = 'Hello!';

$params = array(
   'timestamp' => $timestamp,
   'login'     => $login,
   'phone'     => $phone,
   'text'      => $text,
   'sender'    => $sender,
   'return'    => $return
);

ksort( $params );
reset( $params );

$signature = md5( implode( $params ) . $api_key ); 

$query = "https://test.ru/get/send.php?login=" . $login . "&signature=" . $signature . "&phone=" . $phone . "&sender=" . $sender . "&return=" . $return . "&timestamp=" . $timestamp . "&text=" . urlencode( $text );

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "utf-8" );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120 );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120 );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

$result = curl_exec( $curl );
```

Нужен аналогичный код на Ruby on Rails
Я уже пробивал и `Net::HTTP` и `OpenUri` и `Rest::Client` ответ одинаково не правильный в отличие запроса на Php.

Последние что пробивал:

```
timestamp = '1485942173'
 login = 'admin' 
 sender = 'admin'
 format = 'json'     
 client_phone = '79793665627'
 message = 'Hello!' 
        params = {
            :login => login,
            :phone => client_phone,
            :return => format,
            :sender => sender,
            :text       => message,
            :timestamp  => timestamp }
        api_key = '6t7a7c34914c0fa02f34b4b52d55aa2bb2f3b4b7'
        params_string = params.values.join + api_key
        signature = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params_string) 

query = "https://test.ru/get/send.php?login=" + login + "&signature=" + signature + "&phone=" + client_phone + "&sender=" + sender + "&timestamp=" + timestamp + "&text=" + CGI.escape(message)

uri = URI(query)

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
                                      :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https',
                                      :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) { |http|

                  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

                  response = http.request request

                  resp = JSON.parse(response.body)
  }
```

Comment: Не вижу, где тут Rails. Ruby вижу. И чем описанный код не выполняет задачу? Какое отличие от требуемого запроса?

Comment: В чём проблема-то? Для [mcve] можно использовать httpbin.org, например.

Comment: Не выполняет тем что в ответе приходит ошибка, которая говорит что переменная &signature не корректная, но они идентичные я проверял. А по поводу отличия может параметры не все заданы такие как в php.

Comment: Волшебства не бывает. Если система говорит, что подпись неверная, значит она неверная. Если подписи реально идентичны, значит не идентично то, что подписано.

Comment: По-хорошему, экранировать надо все параметры в URL. И строить его лучше с помощью `URI` из стандартной библиотеки (который сам будет экранировать параметры), а не как у вас, самопально.

Comment: Добавил переменные, может так будет проще понять суть проблемы.

Comment: `URI` мало "просто воткнуть", им надо ещё и пользоваться. Параметры вы по-прежнему запихиваете в него сами.

Comment: Я пробовал даже так результат тот же:   `query = "https://test.ru/get/send.php"`  `uri = URI(query)`   `  params = { :login => login, :signature => signature, :phone =>  client_phone, :sender => sender, :timestamp => timestamp, :text => message} `   `uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params) `  `res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)`